Azure eventgrid creation fails with standard sku
I'm attempting to create an Event Grid for custom topics using the standard tier and encountering an error:
New-AzEventGridTopic_CreateExpanded: C:\path-to-script\Deploy-EventGrid-test.ps1:10:1
Line |
  10 |  New-AzEventGridTopic `
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Create or update to Premium sku is currently not supported.

I get this error whether deploying with Bicep or Powershell. When creating one through the portal, there is no sku/pricing tier option.
Azure documentation lists two tiers: standard and basic, though the Skuname parameter is premium.
Skuname parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.eventgrid/new-azeventgridtopic?view=azps-12.2.0#-skuname and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.eventgrid/new-azeventgridtopic?view=azps-12.2.0#-skuname
This document lists the differences in tiers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/choose-right-tier
It's also listed on the pricing page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/event-grid/
I run into the same problem no matter the location/region.
Here's my PowerShell script:
$subscription = "subscriptionname"
$resourcegroup = "rgname"
$egname = "egname"
$location = "region" 
$sku = "Premium"
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription

New-AzEventGridTopic `
-Name $egname `
-ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup `
-Location $location `
-SkuName $sku


To mix it up a bit, I tried deploying using az cli and got a more helpful error message. The -skuname parameter is still in development and preview, and not available yet. It's frustrating that it's in all of the documentation, yet not available, but that's not entirely surprising.
Deployments work fine without the -skuname parameter, it just deploys it as basic, which I've been using for a few years. I'll just wait to take advantage of the longer TTL and increased throughput that comes with the new Sku.
Argument '--sku' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
(InvalidRequest) Create or update to Premium sku is currently not supported.
Code: InvalidRequest
Message: Create or update to Premium sku is currently not supported.

